# Hide Page on Pageload if condition not met VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security

In my page load, I want to query to see if a user has access to the page, and if he/she does not, I want to make the page (not including master) hidden and alert the user that they have no access. How can I do this? I currently have the query working where it returns false if the user has no access. But how can I make a page hidden without manually making all the controls hidden?

Comment: If YourQuery() = True Then Me.Visible = False End If (where Me = the Page object).

Comment: How do I call the page object? Where Can I see what the object is named?

Comment: Try Me.Page.Visible in your Form_Load event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a user that doesn't have access to a page I would redirect them to a no access page instead of hiding the page itself.

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
    IF accessVaraible = false then
       Response.Redirect("noAccessPage.aspx")
    END IF
    'Do other thing if they have access
END SUB
```